# php array unique on two arrays

Tags: php

Two PHP arrays:

```
$array1 = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$array2 = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
```

Now how can I end up with an array like this:

```
$array3 = array(6,7,8,9,10);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With [`array_diff`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php):

```
$array3 = array_diff($array2, $array1);
```

Comment: But beware the sequence: `array_diff($array1, $array2);` would return an empty array!

Comment: @DanLee: IMHO that's not that sneaky a trap because "taking the difference" (e.g. subtraction) is generally a non-commutative operation.

Answer (score 0):

use array_diff

```
$array3 = array_diff($array2, $array1)
```

Answer (score 0):

As `array_diff` returns a [relative complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_%28set_theory%29#Relative_complement) you can use this code for a full diff, where it doesn't matter on which side the diff should be made:

```
$array3 = array_diff(array_merge($array1, $array2), array_intersect($array1, $array2));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array1 = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$array2 = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);

$output = array_merge(array_diff($array1, $array2), array_diff($array2, $array1));
print_r($output);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => 6 [1] => 7 [2] => 8 [3] => 9 [4] => 10 )
```